# json-framework "Unknown property attribute"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json-framework

Before I used JSON-framework,https://github.com/stig/json-framework/, it was great. But now I get an error "Unknow property attribute". Even when I run the example provided with the framework I have the same error

[image: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/336932Capturede769cran20111123a768213649.png]

Comment: Which Xcode and iOS SDK versions are you building with / against?

Comment: You will need Xcode 4.2 to support ARC (which is needed for compiling the source code you quoted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your Xcode to version 4.2 to get the quoted source code compiled successfully.

Comment: But the same framework is used is facebook-ios-sdk , i use it for facebook connect and it work!

Comment: @Keviin55 Are you using the exact same version of the sbJSON framework within the facebook connect SDK - that would really surprise me? Again, you need Xcode 4.2 to support ARC and the given screenshot shows that there is a ARC specific keyword used.

Comment: ok thank you ! I can not run the update in xcode 4.1? I must re-download xcode 4.2 from the app store?

Comment: @Keviin55 yes, you will need to do a full download.